# When to use " . " or " -> " operators to access attribute or member function?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

In both C, C++ and Objective-C, we can use `.` or `->` to access values or functions. What are the differences or drawbacks between the two?

Answer (score 6):

You can treat `a->b` as `(*a).b` in `C`-Language

Comment: In Objective-C, the . and -> operators have very specific uses!!!!

Answer (score 4):

When you use a pointer to the object to call the member function, you need `->`.
When you use the object to call the member function , you need `.`

for example

```
student Tom; 
student *ptr_Tom = &Tom;  
Tom.func();  
ptr_Tom->func();
```

Answer (score 3):

They operate on different types.  The left hand side of `->` is a pointer (or pointer-like object), and the left hand side of `.` is a value or reference.

Answer (score 3):

In Objective-C, the `.` and `->` operators have very specific uses. There are no options.

You use `.` to access a property or a C-structure member.

You can use `->` to access an instance variable. It can be used to access a public ivar (though you should never have any of these) or if you are referencing an ivar of `self`, it can be any ivar.

Answer (score 2):

If the variable is a pointer to a structure, you use `->`

If it's the structure itself or a c++ reference to the structure, you use `.`

There are no options or tradeoffs to think about, really.

```
struct my_struct {
   int foo;
   float bar;
}

struct my_struct data;

struct my_struct * data_pointer = &data;


data.foo
```

is the same thing as

```
data_pointer->foo
```

Also, technically, you can dereference the pointer then use .

```
(*data_pointer).foo
```

This also works, but you almost never want to write it like that.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
struct t_thing { int a; };
```

You use this syntax:

```
// reference (C++)
void foo(t_thing& pThing) { pThing.a = 1; }

// value
void foo(t_thing pThing) { pThing.a = 1; }

// pointer
void foo(t_thing* const pThing) {
  pThing->a = 1;
  // or
  (*pThing).a = 1;
}
```

Another difference in C++ is that `operator->` may be user-defined, whereas `operator.` may not. `operator->` is often used to access a member of a container such as a smart pointer.

"Drawbacks" are not a concern because it just boils down to be either syntactically correct or incorrect.

In Objective-C, you *could* use `self->ivar` or `object->ivar` for direct ivar access. Typically, you will not write this and use one of the following:

```
// setter via setter method -setIvar:, equivalent to [self setIvar:a];
self.ivar = a;

// setter via getter method -ivar:, equivalent to int a = [self ivar];
int a = self.ivar;
```

Or in some cases you will use direct access where `self` is implicit (i.e. within the scope of an instance method), particularly partially constructed states like an initializer or `-dealloc`:

```
- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (nil == self) return nil;
  ivar = 10; // same as self->ivar = 10;
  return self;
}
```

Finally, 'attribute' really doesn't mean something for these languages. Closest match: Attributes are used by Clang and GCC for special compiler dependent decorations -- e.g. you could use an attribute to mark a function as deprecated.

Comment: nice answered!, and + for Objective-C

Answer (score 1):

`a->b` - Structure dereference ("member b of object pointed to by a") .
`a.b`  -Structure reference ("member b of object a") .

You can overload `->` operation in C++ but not `.`operation

for example:

```
struct mystruct 
{
    int member; 
} 
struct mystruct struct_inst; 
struct mystruct *struct_pointer;

struct_inst.member= var;
struct_pointer->member=var;
```

Or

```
((&struct_inst)->member) = var;
(*struct_pointer).member=var;
```

Comment: `*(struct_inst->member) = var;` is wrong unless both `struct_inst` and `member` are pointers... not a very useful example, and not related to the earlier definition of `mystruct` and `struct_inst`.

Comment: you 100% right typo mistake. fixed! thanks!

Answer (score -2):

`.` should be used when we have Object or reference on left side. 
`->` should be used when we have pointer on left side of operator.

for example

```
class Temp{
    public int a;
}  

Temp *t=new Temp();
Temp t1=*t;
t1.a=10;// used . operator because t1 is Object

t->a=10;//-> operator cause t is pointer..
```

so `t->a` is equivalent to `(*t).a`

Comment: downvoted because there are numerous errors

Comment: whats errors, the code is not working sample but means to explain my statements

Comment: have you tried working through the compilation errors?

Comment: @justin as i said ` the code is not working sample but means to explain my statements` 
`. should be used when we have Object or reference on left side. -> should be used when we have pointer on left side of operator.`

Comment: @rahulmaindargi: justin has a fair point... `Temp t = new Temp();` is an instant memory leak and misleading as use of `new` generally implies pointers but `t` is not a pointer.  Not good to be exposing people who need to ask beginners questions to such code.

Comment: @rahulmaindargi the other obvious problem is lies in the class declaration.

Comment: "whats errors, the code is not working sample but means to explain my statements " -- If you would try to compile it, the compiler would tell you what errors. "used . operator because t is Object" --  `t` is a class instance, but the result of `new` is a pointer.